# Trabalhar com dois bancos de dados no Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel

Estou criando uma aplicação que precisa se conectar com 2 bancos de dados diferentes. Um banco que eu estou criando (MySQL) e um banco que recebi pronto que tenho permissão apenas para consulta (SQL Server). O intuito da aplicação é consultar os dados do banco SQL Server, fazer operações com esses dados e armazená-los no banco MySQL

Sou bem iniciante no Laravel e não sei se é possível trabalhar com os 2 bancos.
Alguém já fez isso ou sabe se funciona?

ATUALIZAÇÃO:

Tentei fazer como sugeria esse [link](http://%20fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections/%22link%22) porém dá erro.

Arquivo database.php:

```
'default' => 'mysql',
'connections' => array(


        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'matriculas',
            'username'  => '*****',
            'password'  => '*****',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        'sqlsrv' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => '10.31.24.2',
            'database' => 'SIGA',
            'username' => '******',
            'password' => '*****',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),

    ),
```

o Controller:

```
class MatriculasController extends BaseController{

        public function formulario(){

        $teste= DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('select * from supervisor.PESSOA');

        dd($teste);

    }

}
```

O erro:

```
Erro no servidor (500)
```

ATUALIZAÇÃO 2:

Percebi que o problema está com o driver "sqlsrv" que não tem no servidor.
O servidor é um CentOS 6 com PHP 5.4.45. Não sei como instalar este driver para essa versão do PHP, não consigo encontrar o pacote RPM correspondente. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que fazer??

Comment: Acho que esse artigo pode te ajudar: esta em inglês: http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

Comment: Você escreveu `conection` com um `n` só. É `connection`.

Comment: @DeeSouza, realmente! Mas ainda assim deu problema, escrevi corretamente e ao carregar a página aparece "Erro no servidor (500)"

Comment: Essa linha já está configurada como true. Mesmo assim não exibe erro nenhum. Se eu errar a sintaxe ou qualquer outra coisa mostra o erro corretamente, neste caso dá erro no servidor.

Comment: Não aparece nada :(

Comment: Sem a linha  `$teste= DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('select * from supervisor.PESSOA');`
 funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Sim, o nome é exatamente como escrevi na consulta

Comment: Funciona com o MySql

Comment: Pelo que entendi, essas extensions são para windows. Estou usando Linux. Se for por causa da conexão com o SQLServer, está tudo ok, tenho outro aplicativo no servidor que usa a função mssql e funciona direitinho.

Comment: Encontrei o problema, vou atualizar a pergunta.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver esse problema, @AmandaLima ?

Comment: Consegui na modo "gambiarra". Fiz uma classe de conexão própria usando  mssql. Descobri que o driver sqlsrv não funciona no servidor que estou trabalhando e não tenho como mudar a versão do PHP instalada

Comment: Para instalar o driver, você só precisa baixar no site da Microsoft (php_sqlsrv_pdo e php_sqlsrv), salvar na pasta do PHP/ext, abrir o arquivo de configuração do PHP, o `php.ini`, criar uma nova referência `extension=php_sqlsrv_pdo` e `extension=php_sqlsrv`. Reinicie o servidor.